# Curl PHP fake error 6: name lookup timed out

Tags: php, curl, dns

I'm using PHP curl_multi() to crawl websites. Due to the sync DNS problem in Libcurl outlined here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315290/4391251), processing of the entire batch breaks with '*Curl error: 6: Couldn't resolve host name: name lookup timed out*' when one of the URL fails to resolve its DNS in time. Unfortunately I can't compile Libcurl with c-ares to make the DNS requests become async.

1. Is there any other known solution to work around this? Perhaps some exotic PHP timeout that I can use to prevent one timed-out DNS resolve from causing all the following DNS requests from timing out as well?
2. If there isn't, then how can I fake/emulate a URL that doesn't resolve its DNS? Right now I'm just running large batches of URLs at a time hoping that one fails to resolve so that I can test for solutions, which obviously/apparently doesn't work too well because of DNS caching.
3. Can settings such as CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT or CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE help to resolve/minimize this problem? Neither of those seem to have any effect for me so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can just add the websites to the hosts file before crawling it, then it should resolve in a millisecond or less, too fast to incur timeouts -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that old answer you link to is only partially correct. (I am the main author of libcurl and I've written most of the code we're talking about here.)

Second, most libcurls in Linux distros and on windows are built with the threaded resolver, which handles asynch name resolving just fine.

But to answer the actual questions: you can avoid doing DNS resolves completely by not using host names. Use IP addresses directly. You can provide those IP address with `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` for the host names you're gonna use. It won't look good, but it should work.

Comment: are you sure its CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE? maybe you meant CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO ?

Comment: on mac i have this problem as well.. Does mac not have a threaded resolver?

Comment: @Wesley: sure it does if you build it that way (the version Apple ships does)