# Timeout not respected when the network url doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony seems to not respect the HttpClient timeout option when setting the timeout option and when the `requestUrl` is a non-existing links. The timeout I set is 2 seconds but the request fails after 5-6 seconds.

```
    $response = $this->request('POST', $requestUrl,
        [
            'json' => [
                "client_id" => "administration",
                "grant_type"=>"password",
                "username"=>$shop->getUsername(),
                "password"=>$shop->getPassword(),
                "scope" => "user-verified"
            ],
            'max_duration' => 2,
            'timeout' => 2
        ]
    );
```

Is there any other option I have to set in order to control this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

curl_multi_exec(), used under the hood in Symfony HttpClient doesn't return response until all DNS (failure or success) is resolved, more info: [cURL multi hanging/ignoring timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297749/curl-multi-hanging-ignoring-timeout).

Since HttpClient [doesn't allow to set](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#configuring-curlhttpclient-options) CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT option, you can try to add the line `options timeout:<desired timeout in seconds>` to `/etc/resolv.conf` to reduce DNS resolve timeouts, more info: [Configuring DNS resolver failover timeout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78041/configuring-dns-resolver-failover-timeout)